# What are the possible ways of detecting cell phones in some small space?

Tags: electromagnetism, sensor

I guess i can somehow use the fact that cell phone is a source of electromagnetic waves. Considering the space of about 8m3 volume. What equipment setup can be used in order to count phones in a given space?

Comment: A cellular tower emulator, but they are illegal without operating license.

Comment: For security or monitoring reasons, there is commercial demand for such devices.  Many companies sell solutions for this, here's one from a google search: http://www.libelium.com/products/meshlium/smartphone-detection/  Also while it is illegal to intercept phone calls without user's permissions, you can legally run your own cell tower emulator in small regions.  I've seen OpenBTS used before.